# Android Studio not warning about non exhaustive switch statments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, enums

This might be a bug; however I am unsure. In `java` `switch` statements thats are non-exhaustive, should produce a warning of sorts in the IDE. In this case, Android Studio 3.0 (B6)

Given the `enum class Foo`

```
public enum  Foo {

  FOO_ONE,
  FOO_TWO
}
```

and then later used in a switch statement as this:

```
switch(fooEnum){
      case FOO_ONE:
     //Do something here 
        break;
    }
```

Shouldn't the compiler warn me in some way, that this switch statement doesn't use all the `Foo` enum options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler should not give a warning, this is an action for a linter. You can enable this exact feature in Android Studio. If you click the button in the very bottom right of the Android Studio window that looks like a little dude's head, there is a "Configure Inspections" button.

Then under "Java-> Control Flow Issues -> Enum 'switch' statement that misses case" enable that option.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and is specific enough to not give false positives (IE when default is included.)

Answer (score 2):

No they shouldn't.  Non-exhaustive switch statements aren't illegal.  Producing a warning would be a compiler specific option at most (and truthfully I think a really really annoying one).  There's nothing in the language which requires a compiler to warn you of anything.  Although there likely is a lint setting that would turn that on, it seems the type of thing lint would do.

Comment: I figured it would be at most an compiler thing the produces a warning. In Xcode / Objective-c this is a standard thing. Is there a way one could get this to work? The reason being is that if more enum options are added to Foo, I would like to know where I have not included it, in every switch case, etc.

Comment: It would be somewhere in settings->Editor->inspections with all the other warning options.  Probably under Java.  There's a few hundred, I have no clue which would do this, although I suspect its there.  Its not a default because non-exhaustive switches are very common, false positives make developers stop caring about warnings.

Comment: In the case of Xcode (probably same thing will happen for linter in Android), if you add a `default` clause, no warning will be shown (of course, `default` will handle all the missing cases!). See [Quick Tip: Don't Default that Switch! (Route 85)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpMIYtl_A98)